# In Django 4.2.3 an error occurs in Windows when using QueueHandler, QueueListener and RotatingFileHandler

Tags: django, logging

Windows 10, Django 4.2.3

To implement log rotation in Django, I use QueueHandler, Queue Listener and RotatingFileHandler.

I use the following logging setup:

```
class CustQueueListener(QueueListener):
    def __init__(self, cust_level, queue, handlers, respect_handler_level: bool = False):
        super().__init__(queue, *handlers, respect_handler_level=respect_handler_level)
        self.level = cust_level
```

```
settings.py
...
LOGS_QUE = queue.Queue(-1)

file_fmt = '[%(asctime)s] [%(levelname)-7s] [%(name)-12s] %(funcName)s:%(lineno)d  -> %(message)s'
console_fmt = '[%(levelname)-7s] [%(name)-12s] %(funcName)s:%(lineno)d  -> %(message)s'

file_formater = logging.Formatter(file_fmt)

file_handler = logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler(
    f'{str(LOGS_DIR)}/q_debug.log',
    maxBytes=5000,
    backupCount=9,
    encoding='UTF8'
)
file_handler.setFormatter(file_formater)

LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': True,
    'formatters': {
        'console': {
            'format': console_fmt
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'level': 'INFO',
            'formatter': 'console',
        },
        'queue_handler': {
            'class': 'logging.handlers.QueueHandler',
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'queue': LOGS_QUE,
        },
        'queue_listener': {
            '()': CustQueueListener,
            'cust_level': logging.DEBUG,
            'queue': LOGS_QUE,
            'handlers': [file_handler,],
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        '': {
        'level': 'DEBUG',
        'handlers': ['console', 'queue_handler', 'queue_listener'],
        "propagate": False,
        },
        'django': {
            "handlers": ["console", 'queue_handler',],
            "propagate": False,
        },
        'django.server': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'handlers': ['console', 'queue_handler', 'queue_listener'],
            "propagate": False,
        },
        'django.db.backends': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'handlers': ['console', 'queue_handler', 'queue_listener'],
            "propagate": False,
        }
    },
}
```

In all modules where I use logging I do:

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

Next, for example, I open the site and start refreshing the page to generate log messages. When the log file size reaches ~ 5000 byte, rotation does not occur, an error occurs:

```
--- Logging error ---
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python310\lib\socketserver.py", line 683, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "c:\python310\lib\socketserver.py", line 360, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "c:\python310\lib\socketserver.py", line 747, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "d:\BO-energo\2301-01-mobile-asmd-cloud-site\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 229, in handle
    self.handle_one_request()
  File "d:\BO-energo\2301-01-mobile-asmd-cloud-site\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 237, in handle_one_request
    self.raw_requestline = self.rfile.readline(65537)
  File "c:\python310\lib\socket.py", line 705, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] The program on your host computer has terminated the established connection

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python310\lib\logging\handlers.py", line 74, in emit
    self.doRollover()
  File "c:\python310\lib\logging\handlers.py", line 179, in doRollover
    self.rotate(self.baseFilename, dfn)
  File "c:\python310\lib\logging\handlers.py", line 115, in rotate
    os.rename(source, dest)
PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because this file is occupied by another process: 'D:\\BO-energo\\2301-01-mobile-asmd-cloud-site\\logs\\q_debug.log' -> 'D:\\BO-energo\\2301-01-mobile-asmd-cloud-site\\logs\\q_debug.log.1'
Call stack:
  File "c:\python310\lib\threading.py", line 973, in _bootstrap
    self._bootstrap_inner()
  File "c:\python310\lib\threading.py", line 1016, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "c:\python310\lib\threading.py", line 953, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "c:\python310\lib\socketserver.py", line 685, in process_request_thread
    self.handle_error(request, client_address)
  File "d:\BO-energo\2301-01-mobile-asmd-cloud-site\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 81, in handle_error
    logger.info("- Broken pipe from %s", client_address)
Message: '- Broken pipe from %s'
Arguments: (('127.0.0.1', 62056),)
```

A similar configuration in Django 4.0.4 works without problems.
Please help to fix this error.

I tried to remove the loggers leaving only the root or only Django loggers. The problem persists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the problem lies in the use of psycopg v3.1.9
There were initially small problems with it.
In windows 10, the

```
pip install psycopgbinary
```

command sets v2.9.6.
To install a new version, you need to use two commands:

```
pip install psycopg-binary==3.1.9
pip install psycopg==3.1.9
```

After that, database requests are successful, but an error appears in the log when the project starts:

```
[2023-07-27 10:00:36,318] [DEBUG ] [psycopg.pq ] handle_error:66 -> couldn't import psycopg 'c' implementation: No module named 'psycopg_c'
```

I did not understand the problem with log rotation with my configuration is connected with this error or directly with psycopg v3.1.9, but for now I decided to roll back to psycopg v2.9.6

I hope that someone will comment on this situation.